# Connection to mongodb hangs after inactivity

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, gunicorn, mongoengine

My connection layers are gunicorn -> mongoengine -> pymongo -> mongodb, all through a django framework. I'm trying to use django-tastypie to set up a REST api on a virtual machine. When I run gunicorn, all connections are fine. However, when I connect again, after about 4-5 minutes of inactivity, the connection hangs.

Why is this happening?